# PHP sort list of subdomains by domain

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a list of domains (array)

```
sub1.dom1.tld1
sub2.dom2.tld2
sub1.sub2.dom1.tld1
sub3.dom1.tld3
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
dom1.tld1
-> sub1.dom1.tld1
-> sub2.dom1.tld1
--> sub1.sub2.dom1.tld1

dom2.tld2
-> sub2.dom2.tld2

dom1.tld3
-> sub3.dom1.tld3
```

I have tried to adapt this, but it doesn't really fit:

[How to alphabetically sort a php array after a certain character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346422/how-to-alphabetically-sort-a-php-array-after-a-certain-character-in-a-string)

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to attack a similar headache before. In the short term I flip the order of the domain components and use a hidden sorting column in a table/view:
`$sortstring = implode('.',array_reverse(explode('.', $domain)));`

In the long term I saved the reverse format of the domain records before saving changes to the DB into a computed field/column so that it didn't have to be re-computed every time the domain list is viewed.

If you don't want that sub-domain, just remove the last element of the array after the flip....

Comment: that's actually a good idea, instead of wasting computing power by creating a complex array sort, just add everything into the computed column and use that one to sort/group

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like this:

```
$array=array(
'sub1.dom1.tld1',
'sub2.dom2.tld2',
'sub1.sub2.dom1.tld1',
'sub2.sub2.dom1.tld1',
'sub3.sub2.dom1.tld1',
'sub3.dom1.tld3');

function cmp($a,$b){
    $a=array_reverse(explode('.',$a));
    $b=array_reverse(explode('.',$b));
    $ca=count($a);
    $cb=count($b);
    $string='';;
    for($i=0,$c=min($ca,$cb);$i<$c;$i++){
        $result=strnatcmp($a[$i],$b[$i]);
        if($result!==0) return $result;

    }
    return $result;
}

usort($array,'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

and the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sub1.dom1.tld1
    [1] => sub1.sub2.dom1.tld1
    [2] => sub2.sub2.dom1.tld1
    [3] => sub3.sub2.dom1.tld1
    [4] => sub2.dom2.tld2
    [5] => sub3.dom1.tld3
)
```

Comment: @gavu    this of course use the approach of array sort but the code is not so complex.It is also generic and can be used with real domains and subdomains arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach similar to @Elementary answer combine to @CBO one:

```php
$domains = [
    'sub.bbb.com',
    'www.aaa.com',
    '*.zzz.com',
    'aaa.com',
    '*.sub.bbb.com',
    'zzz.com',
    'beta.bbb.com',
    'bbb.com',
    'aaa.fr',
];


// @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61461912/1731473
$computeDomainToSort = static function (string $domain): string {
    return \implode(
        '.',
        array_reverse(
            explode('.', $domain,
                // Keep the base domain.tld collapsed for comparison.
                substr_count($domain, '.')
            )
        )
    );
};

\usort($this->domains, static function (string $domain1, string $domain2) use ($computeDomainToSort): int {
    $domain1 = $computeDomainToSort($domain1);
    $domain2 = $computeDomainToSort($domain2);

    return strnatcmp($domain1, $domain2);
});
```

That way, given domains will be sorted like this:

```
aaa.com
www.aaa.com
aaa.fr
bbb.com
beta.bbb.com
sub.bbb.com
*.sub.bbb.com
zzz.com
*.zzz.com
```

The main difference is on the `$computeDomainToSort` lambda function, where I keep the base `domain.tld` onto one piece to have a more natural sorting.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is a late answer, but here it how i achieved it

First i have function to get the host name from subdomain

```
function getHost($a)
{
    $tld = preg_replace('/.*\.([a-zA-Z]+)$/', '$1', $a);
    return trim(preg_replace('/.*(([\.\/][a-zA-Z]{2,}){' . ((substr_count($a, '.') <= 2 && mb_strlen($tld) != 2) ? '2,3' : '3,4') . '})/im', '$1', $a), './');
}
```

Next you need to loop through the subdomains and get their main domain and store it in array

```
$domains = [
    'sub.bbb.com',
    'www.aaa.com',
    '*.zzz.com',
    'aaa.com',
    '*.sub.bbb.com',
    'zzz.com',
    'beta.bbb.com',
    'bbb.com',
    'aaa.fr',
];


$allMainDomains = array();

foreach ($domains as $domainValue) {
    if (!in_array(getHost($domainValue), $allMainDomains)) {
        array_push($allMainDomains, getHost($domainValue));
    }
}
```

What we did is, we store all main domains in an array `$allMainDomains` and verified not duplicates by using `in_array` function

Next we can loop through the `$allMainDomains` and `$domains` like so

```
foreach ($allMainDomains as $mainDomain) {
    echo '<br>' . $mainDomain . '<br>';

    foreach ($domains as $subDomain) {
        if (getHost($subDomain) == $mainDomain) {
            echo '<br>' . $subDomain . '<br>';
        }
    }
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

**Note: The only thing you might need to modify is the getHost function because it skips the multiple dots (.) domains**

Result

[image: Resul]